# How do I solve the following integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x)\int_{\sqrt{2kx}}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration

Can anyone please show how should I solve this integral

(a general idea to solve other such integration problems):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-x)\int_{\sqrt{2kx}}^{\infty}\exp\left(\frac{-t^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Use Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integrate by switching the order
\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\int_{\sqrt{2kx}}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}{d}t \>{d}x
=&\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2k}t^2}
e^{-x}dx\>dt\\
=& \int_0^\infty \left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac1k )t^2}\right)dt\\
=& \sqrt{\frac\pi2}\bigg( 1-\sqrt{\frac k{1+k}}\bigg)
\end{align}

Comment: how did you manipulate the limits?

Comment: @indmath - Note that the integration region is between the curve $t=\sqrt{2kx}$ and the $t$-axis.

Comment: Got it. Thank You